# Gulp.watch dosen't work when I use intellij idea to develop

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, gulp

When I use sublime text to edit files and save,Gulp.watch works well,but Gulp.watch will not keep watching files if I use intellij idea to develop.Just because intellij idea can save files automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn off "Safe write" in

> File -> Settings -> System Settings -> Use "safe write" (save changes
>   to a temporary file first)

Works for me in IntelliJ IDEA 15.